# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. in VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, vscode-debugger, tflite

Good day! I am a beginner in Visual Code and as I was about to debug my app, this came as an error in my debug console

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Multiple build operations failed.
      Cannot parse result path string: 
      Cannot parse result path string: 
   > Cannot parse result path string: 
   > Cannot parse result path string: 

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

this is my build.gradle, I tried changig the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion a few times but it still gave me the same result.

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.obscura"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

If I Thank you so much in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the gradle version. Just change the gradle to the latest version. Your error will be gone.

If you are on windows go File -> Project Structure, on project change the gradle version.

Comment: Good day! I can't seem to find the Project Structure in my File. I am currently using VSCode.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74312852/how-to-change-vscode-gradle-version

Comment: check the given link above

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this error in Expo, it is likely due to incompatible versions of some dependencies in your project.

run `npx expo-doctor`

then

`npx expo install --fix`

This fix the issue for me.